# Adding a password to an Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: password, live-cd

I've made a personal Live CD on Ubuntu builder but I didn't add a password to the Live CD.

Is it possible to add a password to a live CD in any way? (before or after creating the CD)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to edit the casper scripts.

This varies slightly between versions of Ubuntu, see:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Removing_the_.28Casper.29_Autologin

Answer (score 0):

As [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#Setting_a_Password) page says:

> You can set a password during a LiveCD session by opening a terminal,
> and typing in:
>
> ```
> sudo passwd ubuntu
> ```

Note that this will set the password only for the current session (which is far less useful).

Comment: some source of verification would be useful for this answer I think

Comment: That method only sets a password for the current session and will not persist with a reboot.